# How to avoid Restart Bluetooth Printer after print?

Tags: printing, bluetooth, windows-mobile-6.5, 32feet

I have developed windows mobile 6.1 application which search nearby Bluetooth devices and send files.Also I did print functionality to print document on Bluetooth printer.

First time print functionality is working perfectly fine but when I print the document again, then I need to restart the printer and then after it will print.

Is there any solution to avoid restart printer??

Below is my print code from reference of https://32feet.codeplex.com/discussions/355451

```
private void btPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        // Activate BT
        BluetoothRadio.PrimaryRadio.Mode = RadioMode.Connectable;
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        // Connect  
        BluetoothAddress btAddress;
        btAddress = BluetoothAddress.Parse("0022583165F7");            
        BluetoothClient btClient = new BluetoothClient();
        try
        {
            btClient.Connect(new BluetoothEndPoint(btAddress, BluetoothService.SerialPort));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            return;
        }
        // Send data
        string CPCLStr1 =
            "! 0 200 200 210 1" + Environment.NewLine +
            "ML 25" + Environment.NewLine +
            "TEXT 7 0 10 20" + Environment.NewLine +
            "Just" + Environment.NewLine +
            "Testing" + Environment.NewLine +
            "ENDML" + Environment.NewLine +
            "FORM" + Environment.NewLine +
            "PRINT" + Environment.NewLine;

        // Convert CPCL String to byte array
        byte[] CPCLbytes1 = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(CPCLStr1);

        NetworkStream ns = btClient.GetStream();
        ns.Write(CPCLbytes1, 0, CPCLbytes1.Length);

        btClient.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Although you close the client stream, the printer seems to wait some time before it resets it's session.

Try to send a <EOF> or <EOT> byte at the end.

Acording to CPCL reference guide there is no simple reset command as with ESC/p for example ({esc}@).

Doing a device reset after every print seems an overkill.

EDIT: SDK sample for sendFile:

```
                Byte[] cpclLabel = Encoding.Default.GetBytes("! 0 200 200 406 1\r\n" + "ON-FEED IGNORE\r\n"
                + "BOX 20 20 380 380 8\r\n"
                + "T 0 6 137 177 TEST\r\n"
                + "PRINT\r\n");
```

The above runs fine on my RW420 without the need to reset between prints.

Comment: Thanks for the reply josef.But how to send EOT byte at the end? I mean I have searched on google for that but could't found any specific solution to send EOT tag.I also read CPCL reference guide for that but they did not explain in detail.

Comment: you add 0x04 (EOT char, aka EOF, these are the same) at the end of your byte buffer. For example by ending the last line "PRINT\r\n" with "PRINT" + Environment.NewLine + "\x04";

Comment: Still same problem josef.Not working "PRINT" + Environment.NewLine + "\x04".Do you have any other solution or source??

Comment: Try (flushing and) closing the NetworkStream before you close the client. The BT printer seems to be still waiting for more data and does not see the job as finished. Also the manual states the printer needs ALWAYS a PRINT<0x0D><0x0A> at the end as Job control end command (PRINT + CR + LF). Possibly Environment.NewLine does not send a CR+LF at end, try coding it directly using "\x0d\x0a".

Comment: Still it is not working josef.Do you have any other solution?

Comment: Sorry, no more ideas. Are you using the right media? Did you try the ZebraSDK sample SendFile demo?

Comment: Error comes in btClient.Connect line.Error is "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it".

Comment: That error either means the printer is not accepting the connection, ie it can hold only one connection, it is still busy... Did you close the connection gracefully after usage? I suggest closing the stream first (ns.Close), then the connection (btClient.Disconnect(), btClient.Close()), then dispose the client (bt.Dispose()) and then set it to NULL (btClient=null). Or you create a singleton btClient that is used and kept for the lifetime of your app.

Comment: I have done all things but still the same problem.Error comes while connection socket.You can see the code in this link. https://www.symbolsource.org/Public/Metadata/NuGet/Project/32feet.NET/3.5.0.3/Release/.NETFramework,Version%3Dv0.0,Profile%3DCompactFramework/InTheHand.Net.Personal/InTheHand.Net.Personal/Net.Sockets/IrDAClient.cs?ImageName=InTheHand.Net.Personal. where you can find Connect() function where I got error.

Comment: The link is standard 32feet code. But it does not show how you setup, close and dispose the connection before you send another print job. I never had such problem with portable Bluetooth printers so far. But is close, dispose and NUL the used objects before I start another print.

Comment: @Harsh have you been able to solve the problem, I am having a similar problem currently, I am working with the Printooth library here. https://github.com/mazenrashed/Printooth After a successful print. I will have to restart the printer before it can print again.